# How to use auto suggest text box in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Code I found on net for the same is :

```
driver.findElement(locator).click();
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(value);
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

But I don't know which value I have to enter and what is Keys in 3rd line

Comment: The value is what is being entered on the line. Look in the code to see what "value" holds.. Keys.TAB is essentially clicking on the TAB button, thus cycling through any suggestions that might come up.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(locator).click();
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(value);
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

You have to enter a value to suggest from text box. 
Ex: If you need to suggest your state, you can enter state name first letters.

Then the "key" mean selenium webdriver command. you can specify which key should press.

Ex: Manually you have to enter the value and press down arrow twice and press enter.Like this you can specify the keyboard keys.